# how can I merge dask dataframe all portions together

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, dask

I have a sales DataFrame which has 28M rows and also some other dataframes as well an example a `Product` DataFrame.

When I first convert pandas dataframes to Dask dataframe:

```
  sales_dd = dd.from_pandas(Sales, npartitions=3) #28M rows
  product_dd = dd.from_pandas(Product, npartitions=3) #600 rows
```

after converting `Dask Dataframe` I can see my data with;

```
  sales_dd.tail()

             Date      ProductNo    Total_Sales
28499962    20160730       537        3.0
28499963    20170528       561        12.0
28499964    20160628       534        10.0
28499965    20170112       544        160.0
28499966    20170907       574        0.0
```

and after I tries to merge these two dask DataFrame like this:

```
productsales = dd.merge(sales_dd, product_dd, on='ProductNo', how='left')
```

then when I check last DataFrame;

```
productsales.tail()



               Date    ProductNo    Total_Sales   x     y     z  ....
9440495     20171202       579        5.0         .     .     .
9440496     20171017       581        2.0         .     .     .
9440497     20160906       519        9.0
9440498     20160628       544        10.0        .     .     .
9440499     20170907       574        0.0         .     .     .
```

As we can see productsales table is only 900k rows.

My question is how can I merge all DataFrame together? Do I have to make no portion? What is the fastest way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The numeric index on the left does not necessarily give the number of rows, it is the index value of the dataframe, which can hold other values than a simple incrementing index.

Instead, I recommend computing the length of the dataframe

```
>>> len(df)
```

Comment: Hey @MRocklin True, it is same row as before but why it happened?